# Unable to get Perl redirection working in C# with background worker

Tags: c#, perl, redirect

I've been trying to get a Perl script to give up its output to a List box in C# without any luck.

I've been looking on this site and others and tried multiple combinations but are still not having any joy with it, perhaps something to do with trying to do it via the background worker?

My code below, help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The backgroundworker object on which the time consuming operation shall be executed
    /// </summary>
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;
    private String _dirPath = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // On completed do the appropriate task
    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnOpenFolder.Enabled = true;
        btnCancel.Enabled = false;
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here you play with the main UI thread, update a progress bar or status label
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Perl\bin\perl.exe");
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp\";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Temp\dirdupes.pl";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = _dirPath;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();

        //For testing
        //p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        //p.StartInfo.Arguments = "dir/s";      

        //For testing
        //StreamReader sr = p.StandardError;
        //string line;
        //line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //listBox1.Text = line;

        using (StreamReader std_out = p.StandardOutput, std_err = p.StandardError)
        {
            do
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(std_out.ReadToEnd()); 
                listBox1.Items.Add(std_err.ReadToEnd());
            } while (!std_out.EndOfStream) ;
        }

        p.WaitForExit();

        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
            return;
        }
        //Report 100% completion on operation completed
        //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
    }

    private void btnOpenFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Open folder browser for user to select the folder to scan
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Store selected folder path
            _dirPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        btnOpenFolder.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;

        //Start the async operation here
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            //Stop/Cancel the async operation here
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I ended up using this code which managed to display the Perl scripts output to my listbox

```
void p_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null && e.Data.Length > 0) this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data)));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1));
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        var args = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        args.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        //p.StartInfo.FileName = "perl.exe";
        args.Arguments = @"/C perl.exe C:\Temp\dirdupes.pl " + _dirPath;
        args.CreateNoWindow = true;
        args.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        args.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        args.RedirectStandardError = true;
        args.UseShellExecute = false;
        p = Process.Start(args);

        p.OutputDataReceived += p_DataReceived;
        p.ErrorDataReceived += p_DataReceived;
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: @reinierpost no output whatsoever using a Perl script, if I change the filename to an executable file I get output.

Comment: Yes, the "filename" is supposed to be a "program" name (i.e., perl.exe).  See my full Answer.  You can supply the Perl script as an Argument (along with anything else you need, like an argument to the Perl script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the Process to launch like this:

```
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp\";
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Temp\dirdupes.pl";
```

to get past problems launching the process.  Perhaps that's not where you got hung up?

After that, though, you need to take out this line:

```
p.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

After that, it works for me!  However, every line of (standard) output is going to show up as a single item in your listBox.  Perhaps you need to break up the output to put each line of output as a separate listBox item?

Comment: Hi jimtut, I still can't get it to work with your example (I must have something else wrong... I'll dropbox the Perl script and the zipped project tonight when I get home. It's gotta be something easy I've messed up... I also need it to process the folder selected with _dirPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

Comment: Tried something different and now it displays to my listbox, the cancel button doesn't work but I should be able to sort it out. I've added the code I used to the original post.

Comment: Hi jimtut here's the dropbox link, a guy at work modified my original code and doesn't use the background worker anymore, I'm still interested in getting this to work though, i'm sure I can use it on other app ideas I have. https://www.dropbox.com/s/11nla5pxdley8fx/PERLGUI.rar?dl=0 currently it's coming up with a cross thread error trying to update the listbox.

Comment: Two things.  1) Out of the box, I'm getting a run-time error about cross-threading stuff.  You can't have the background worker make changes to the main thread, without a LOT more threading knowledge than I have!  Move all of the BG code from `backgroundWorker1_DoWork()` and put it at the bottom of `btnOpenFolder_Click()`.  2) Modify the `psi.Arguments` line to pass the dir name, like `psi.Arguments = @"C:\Temp\dirdupes.pl " + _dirPath;`